# memcpy issue -> trying to copy an array of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, memcpy, memmove

I am completely lost on why memcpy or memmove is not working for me.

I am trying to copy a array of struct (joblist) to another array of same struct (Q) to use for data manipulation, while keeping my original array intact.

I have spent a lot of time on SO and google troubleshooting this and I cannot find out why it won't work.

```
    Q = new AdjacencyList[numjobs + 1]; //create a queue
    // Q = joblist;
    memmove(&Q, &joblist, sizeof(AdjacencyList) );
    Q[0].jobnum = 30;
```

I tried to just make Q = joblist, but then when I changed a value in one, it changed in both.

```
    struct AdjacencyList  {
    NodeType state; // what is present state of job? 
    NodePath path; // is job part of critical path?
    int jobnum;
    int edges;     
    int tocount;
    int fromcount;          
    int to[50];      
    int from[50]; 
    };
    AdjacencyList *joblist;
    AdjacencyList *Q;
```

This is the struct I created.

```
*** Error in `p5.out': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0989e8c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x47975143]
/lib/libc.so.6[0x4797b984]
/lib/libc.so.6[0x4797cd28]
/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x20)[0x47d8d9e0]
/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdaPv+0x1c)[0x47d8da3c]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

SUB

Comment: If `joblist` and `Q`were `std::vector<AdjacencyList>` you wouldn't have to mess around with either `new` or `memcpy`.

Comment: I would use a vector but this is a university data-structures assignment and we are not allowed to use anything from STL. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way you call `memmove(dst, src, sizes)`. Is not correct. It should be

```
memmove(Q, joblist, sizeof(AdjacencyList) * (numjobs + 1));
```

UPDATE:

Like its name, `memmove` operates on memory. It simply copies `sizes` bytes data from `src` to `dst`.

If you want to copy an array of n objects to `Q`, you must tell the function the total size of the data you want to copy, that is `size of each objects * number of objects`. I don't know how many objects you need to copy, `numjobs + 1` is only an example. If you want to copy `numjobs` it should be `sizeof(AdjacencyList) * numjobs`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have pulled every last hair out on this one. Can you tell me why the * (numjobs + 1)?

Answer (score 1):

```
memmove(&Q, &joblist, sizeof(AdjacencyList) );
```

is wrong and results in undefined behavior. It copies `sizeof(AdjacencyList)` bytes from the address of `joblist` to the address of `Q`.

What you need to use is:

```
memmove(Q, joblist, sizeof(AdjacencyList) );
```

to copy one object from `joblist` to `Q`. If you want to copy `numjobs + 1` objects, you need to use:

```
memmove(Q, joblist, sizeof(AdjacencyList)*(numjobs + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You guys are all so helpful. I understand now why the * (numjobs + 1). Makes a world of sense.